# Run Python script on Terminal and keep using the terminal afterwards

Tags: python, linux

I have a script that I activate via the terminal that listens to events. I want to keep using the terminal after the script runs, but the script is running and I can't type anything. The only way I know that lets me keep typing is by using the Ctrl + C combination, but this stops the script.

So how can I run the script in the background and keep using the terminal without terminating it?

Edit: I tried to use the '&' operator but it didn't work:
[image]

Comment: That's more of a "how do I use my shell?" question, but you can run commands in the background by adding `&` to the command line.

Comment: Why do you say `&` didn't work? The picture you posted shows the opposite. It's just that your output got interleaved with the prompt.

Comment: @melpomene I tried it but it didn't work, I edited my question and added a screenshot

Comment: Also, my first dupe hammer :)

Comment: Well it didn't work because I still can't type...

Comment: OK, I had to hit the Enter key for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your script in the background with:

```
python myscript.py &
```

If your script does output something you can suppress the output with:

```
python myscript.py 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Or save the output for later:

```
python myscript.py 1>myoutputfile 2>&1 &
# ...
less myoutputfile
```

Another alternative would be to use for example [screen](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Screen/) or [tmux](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tmux/).